# Seek advice on tables responsive design

Tags: responsive-design

I am pretty new to web developement and seek your advice on how to make my website readable on mobile phones.

This is how it looks on desktop:
[image]

When browsing mobile it looks like this:
[image]

The code I am using is this:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><div>
<h2>
<Checkkrediter - Ett alternativ till traditionella företagslån
</h2>
<p>
På Check-kredit.se kan du jämföra olika typer av checkkrediter och företagslån. Checkkredit, även kallat checkräkningskredit, är ett snabbt & smidigt alternativ istället för företagslån där företaget endast betalar ränta på utnyttjat belopp. 
</p>
</div></td>
<td>[everest_form id="926"]</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The site is using Wordpress.

I like to seek advice on how to make my table (or alternative DIV?) so that the column for the everest form is showing below the info text when browsing the site on mobile etc.

Appreciate all input :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you started:
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/PoJoWmd

In general you want to avoid using tables for layout. They will complicate your life and they aren't the way of the future. My example uses flexbox which is well supported now and if you get the hang of using this it will help you in the future.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="intro">
    <h2>
      Checkkrediter - Ett alternativ till traditionella företagslån
    </h2>
    <p>
      På Check-kredit.se kan du jämföra olika typer av checkkrediter och företagslån. Checkkredit, även kallat checkräkningskredit, är ett snabbt & smidigt alternativ istället för företagslån där företaget endast betalar ränta på utnyttjat belopp.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="form">
    <p>Form content here</p>
    [everest_form id="926"]
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.wrapper > div {
  flex: 1 1;
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 350px; /* adjust as needed */
}
```

Here's a good flexbox link for you:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/